# Paginator url erorr in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-pagination

I am trying to make a paginator for my articles django page. but when I try to go to next pages I get an error ("page not found" and "No Article matches the given query.") and I don't know where I am doing wrong. I appreciate your help...
##########
My views.py:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, Http404
from .models import Article, Category


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
context = {
    "articles": Article.objects.published()
}
return render(request, 'website/home.html', context)


def detail(request, slug):
context = {
    "article": get_object_or_404(Article.objects.published(), slug=slug)
}
return render(request, 'website/detail.html', context)


def article(request, page=1):
articles_list = Article.objects.published()
paginator = Paginator(articles_list, 2)
articles = paginator.get_page(page)
context = {
    "articles": articles,
    "category": Category.objects.filter(status=True)
}
return render(request, 'website/article.html', context)


def category(request, slug):
cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, status=True)
context = {
    "category": cat.articles.filter(status='Published')
}
return render(request, 'website/category.html', context)
```

#######
My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home, detail, article, category

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
path('', home, name='home'),
path('article/<slug:slug>', detail, name='detail'),
path('article', article, name='article'),
path('article/<int:page>', article, name='article'),
path('category/<slug:slug>', category, name='category')
]
```

The related part of article.html page:

```
  <div class="blog-pagination">
          <ul class="justify-content-center">
            {% if articles.has_previous %}
              <li class="disabled"><a>
                  href="{% url 'website:article' articles.previous_page_number %}"
                  <i class="icofont-rounded-left"
                     ></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="#"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            {% if articles.has_next %}
          <li><a href="{% url 'website:article' articles.next_page_number %}">
              <i class="icofont-rounded-right"
                 ></i></a></li>
          {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ulrs are checked one after another so

```
path('article/<slug:slug>', detail, name='detail'),
```

is used, try replacing this one with

```
path('article/<int:page>', article, name='article'),
```

I mean the int one should go first on the `urlpaterns` list